# Edit files with sed and save the result to different files whose names are based on the original file names

Tags: sed, files

I have a large (~300) set of .csv files, each of which are ~200k lines long, with a regular filename pattern:

```
outfile_n000.csv
outfile_n001.csv
outfile_n002.csv
.
.
.
outfile_nXXX.csv
```

I need to extract a range of lines (100013-200013) from each file, and save that extracted region to a new .csv file, appending a `ptally_` prefix to differentiate it from the original file, while preserving the original file.

I know that I can use

`sed -n '100013,200013p' outfile_nXXX.csv > ptally_outfile_nXXX.csv`

to do this to a single file, but I need a way to automate this for large batches of files.  I can get close by using the `-i` option in sed to do so:

`sed  -iptally_*  -n '100013,200013p' outfile_nXXX.csv > ptally_outfile_nXXX.csv`

but this writes the extracted lines to `outfile_nXXX.csv`, and leaves the original file renamed as `ptally_outfile_nXXX.csv`, as this is the purpose of `-i`.

Likewise, brace expansion in bash won't do the trick, as brace expansion and wildcards don't mix:

`sed  --n   10013,20013p *.csv > {,ptally_}*.csv`

Any elegant ways to combine the extraction and renaming into a simpler process?  Currently, I'm using a bash script to perform the swap between the `outfile_nXXX.csv` and `ptally_outfile_nXXX.csv` filenames, but I would prefer a more straightforward workflow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

```
for f in outfile_n???.csv; do
  sed -n '100013,200013p' "$f" > ptally_"$f"
done
```

---

Alternatively, depending on your exact actual requirements, it may be more applicable to use [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html).  Some of the [GNU extensions](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) extend its power considerably.

Comment: Or simply `sed -n "100013,200013w ptally_$f" "$f"` inside the loop

Comment: Works perfectly, just what I needed!  I had tried a few variations on a `for` loop, but hadn't gotten it quite right.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not `sed`, but quite elegant way:

```
awk 'NR >= 100013 && NR <= 200013 {print > "ptally_" FILENAME}' outfile_nXXX.csv
```

For bulk extracting to new, appropriate files do:

```
awk 'FNR >= 100013 && FNR <= 200013 {print > "ptally_" FILENAME}' outfile_n*
```

Also, you can store filename into the variable before passing it to the `sed`:

```
filename="outfile_nXXX.csv"

sed -n '100013,200013p' "$filename" > "ptally_$filename"
```

Comment: `XXX` is a placeholder, not part of the actual name of the file.  Your last example with storing it in a variable doesn't make sense at all given that there are around 300 files to be handled.

Comment: @Wildcard It was just example, not working solution. Idea. Sure, it should be for loop, iterating through all 300 files. And `outfile_nXXX.csv` is representing the general file name. Anyway, `awk` solution is more elegant, so I didn't  developing `bash` way far enough :)